# Метод для добавления элемента

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Народ можете подсказать просто я что то жостко запутался

```
public class Massiv  <T> implements CRUD {
    private T val[];

    public Massiv() {
         val = (T[]) new Object[10];
    }

    public Massiv(int sizes) {
        val = (T[])new Object[sizes];
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object obj) {
        Massiv massiv = new Massiv();
        for (int i = 0; i <val.length+1 ; i++) {
        }

}
```

У нас есть конструктор который создаёт иницализирует массив размером 10. Я не могу понять как мне увеличить этот массив и записать в него ещё какой либо объект. П

Answer (score 1):

> Я не могу понять как мне увеличить этот массив и записать в него ещё какой либо объект.

Изменить (*именно изменить, а не создать новый массив бОльшего размера*) размер массива после его создания невозможно, так как массивы имеют постоянный размер, который задается при его создании.

Как вариант, Вы можете реализовать технику, которая используется в `ArrayList`: если при очередном добавлении массив заполнен, то можно создать новый массив бОльшего размера, куда переместить все элементы старого массива и добавить новый элемент уже в этот, новый массив.

Или можете просто вместо массива использовать какую-нибудь коллекцию, например, тот же `ArrayList<T>`.

Пример с использованием `ArrayList<T>`:

```
public class ExampleStorage<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> mData;

    public ExampleStorage() {
        mData = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        mData.add(value);
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < mData.size()) {
            return mData.get(i);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect index");
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

---

```
ExampleStorage<Integer> storage = new ExampleStorage<>();

storage.add(2);
storage.add(3);

for (int i = 0; i< storage.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(storage.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Хорошо а если представить что нужно добавить елемент не в массив а в хранилище

Comment: @ВладКеся, Что здесь Вы подразумеваете под `хранилище`?

Comment: Та что то я совсем запутался. Под хранилищем пониаю  массив тогда попробыать через ArrayList?

Comment: @ВладКеся, Да, вместо массива можете использовать `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: А можешь маленький пример

Comment: @ВладКеся, Добавил.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас разберусь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48906/discussion-between---and-post-zeew).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void add(Object obj) {
    T a[] = (T[]) new Object[val.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < val.length; ++i)
           a[i] = val[i];
    a[val.length] = (T) obj;
    val = a;
}
```